# Android manifestPlaceholders from gradle.properties

Tags: android, gradle, build, manifest

I want to open an activity on link click (show action chooser with app name). All works fine, action chooser is shown with my app, but only if I do not use property name in manifestPlaceholder, else default browser opens (without any errors).

I have this lines in gradle.properties file:

```
HOST_NAME_DEV="dev.mysite.com"
HOST_NAME_PROD="mysite.com"
```

I want to create a manifestPlaceholder like this:

```
// in manifest
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
             android:host="${host}"
             android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>

//in build.gradle
productFlavors {
        production {
            manifestPlaceholders = [host: HOST_NAME_PROD]
        }
        develop {
            manifestPlaceholders = [host: HOST_NAME_DEV]
        }
}
```

And it does not work.

But if I paste string into the manifestPlaceholder all works fine:

```
productFlavors {
        production {
            manifestPlaceholders = [host: "mysite.com"]
        }
        develop {
            manifestPlaceholders = [host: "dev.mysite.com"]
        }
}
```

In this way all works fine too:

```
productFlavors {
        production {
            resValue "string", "host", HOST_NAME_PROD
        }
        develop {
            resValue "string", "host", HOST_NAME_DEV
        }
    }

// and in manifest
android:host="@string/host"
```

But I want to use manifestPlaceholders.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Try this way from your **gradle.properties** variable : `manifestPlaceholders = [host: project.property('HOST_NAME_PROD')]`

Comment: "And it does not work" -- what does "it does not work" mean? What is the actual behavior? What are the error messages that you are getting?

Comment: @CommonsWare when I click on link an activity with intent-filter as above opens, but only if I use string in manifestPlaceholders (manifestPlaceholders = [host: "dev.mysite.com"]) or string res (resValue "string", "host", HOST_NAME_PROD)

Comment: @JeelVankhede still not working

Answer (score 5):

Problem: Data injecting with "(Double Quotes) in your manifest.

Solution: Remove "(Double Quotes) from your values of gradle.properties that it.
Just like this:

```
HOST_NAME_DEV=dev.mysite.com
HOST_NAME_PROD=mysite.com
```

Comment: You are a hero...I have been struggling to solve an issue, and removing my quotes solved it.  Thanks for a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with the double quotes when using `buildConfigField` to replace `manifestPlaceholders`. Annoyingly this did not cause compile issue only found in runtime. Buildconfigfields require the quotes for them to be rendered as a valid Java String.

**Before:**

properties file

```
config.AUTH_DOMAIN = "\"myDomain\""
```

build.gradle

```
def authDomain = config.AUTH_DOMAIN   

android{
      defaultConfig{
        buildConfigField("String", "AUTH_DOMAIN", "$authDomain")
    
        manifestPlaceholders = [authDomain: authDomain]
    
       }
    }
```

Manifest: `<data android:host=""myDomain"" />`

**After:**

properties file (removed extra the quotes)

```
config.AUTH_DOMAIN = "myDomain"
```

build.gradle

```
def authDomain = config.AUTH_DOMAIN

android{
  defaultConfig{
  //add the quotes or buildConfigField won't compile
    buildConfigField("String", "AUTH_DOMAIN", "\"$authDomain\"")

    manifestPlaceholders = [authDomain: authDomain]

   }
}
```

Manifest: `<data android:host="myDomain" />`